# utility function for tcp header and payload -- is there any Kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I need to extract a tcp header and payload from skb buffer. Basically I will be blocking specific http get request I know there is a function to extract iphdr like `const struct iphdr *ip = ip_hdr(skb);` but need to extract tcp header and data.

Comment: Grepping for `ip_hlen` will probably get you there.

Comment: @wildplasser can u please tell what if I use `sk_buff->data` for getting get request fetching and `sk_buff->head+sk_buf->transport_header` can this bring to `tcp header` .Is`transport_header` is the "the offset" of transport

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/net/ip.h In linix, it is called `ip_hdrlen()` , so it seems. There probably is another similar function/macro for the tcp header size. Take a look at how others do it (iptables/ipchans/bpf). I do think it is a bad idea to do filtering at this level; you could easily disrrupt the tcp state-machine(s).